# How to give URL in codeigniter route file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display my page url like this below

**For Home page (after login)**

www.domain.com/username

**For Aboutme page**

www.domain.com/username/about

**My route file line**

This one worked for home page

```
$route['(:any)'] = "pages/userList";    //This worked for home page
```

But This one not worked, This page also goes for homepage

```
$route['(:any)/about'] = "pages/about";   //Not worked
```

Comment: Try to switch places of those routes in file. E.g. first `$route['(:any)/about'] = "pages/about";` than `$route['(:any)'] = "pages/userList";`. Remember that wildcard route need to be at the end of all possible routes.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Worked . post your answer at feed @Tpojka

Comment: No problem. I posted it in answer so you can accept it as well.

Comment: You will see later to use the (:any) as the first segment in the rule is not the best way. What about for instance if you will need create a example.com/blog/about sub-page? You won't be able to create it because the 'blog' can be a registered user name. Other disadvantage of use (:any) is that you have to define all of your controller/actions in the route config (otherwise (:any) will catch them ) so you cannot use the default 'example.com/class/function/id/' functionality. (e.g: example.com/foo/bar automatically calls your Foo controller Bar method with id parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is because of precedence of routes in `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` file. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) says next:

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

Obeying that rule, very specific routes should appear first and most general routes need to be at the end of file. In your case it would be like:

```
$route['(:any)/about'] = "pages/about";
$route['(:any)'] = "pages/userList";
```

Answer (score 1):

(:any) will catch everything, so it shouldn't be the first rule.

It would be better to use any segment before username, for example:

www.domain.com/user/username then rule is:

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "pages/userList/$1";
```

It will match for: www.domain.com/user/adam, www.domain.com/user/bob, etc...

for this: www.domain.com/username/about

```
$route['about/(:any)'] = "pages/about/$1";
```

It will match for: www.domain.com/about/adam, www.domain.com/about/bob, etc...
In your controller you can get the username:

```
$username = $this->uri->rsegment(3);
```

Comment: You for got to add 1 after dollar sign in the about route

Comment: ok home address like $route['(:any)'] this one worked.. But if i give about url like $route['about/(:any)'] means , Is this working?.